# Is there an area on Stack Overflow where I can post helpful programs?

Tags: discussion, help-center

I was hoping there was an area on this website where I am able to post programs that might help people if they needed to do a similar thing and where I am able to look at what other people wrote.

Please link me if this exits.

Comment: This is exactly what GitHub is for. You should check it out. There's a good free course for it and Git on Udacity if you've never used either one before. Also check out [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if you want ideas for the kinds of software people are looking for but can't find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only areas we have are for questions and answers. (Well, there's also chat, I guess, but that's mostly for socializing, not for content creation.)

As such, **if you want to share helpful information or programs, then you will need to do it in the form of a question and answer**. Note that [it is perfectly okay—even encouraged—to ask and answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You just need to make sure that you follow the Q&A format, which means coming up with a plausible scenario where your code is useful and solves a practical programming problem. Pose the scenario as the question, and then post the code (and an explanation) as an answer to that question. Don't just treat the question like a blog post. If you don't ask a question, or you post the solution as part of the question, then the question *will* be closed and probably deleted. Also, be willing and open-minded to accept *alternative* approaches as answers from other users. That's one of the things that makes this platform successful.

People are often reluctant to do this, but I'm a huge fan of sharing information this way via self-answers. You just have to do it following our standard format, and that can take some time and care. It's difficult enough to write a good question when you are having a problem; it's even harder to come up with a question after the fact, when you already have the solution.

I should also point out that it's best if you post *snippets* of code, rather than the full program. We don't need to see all the boilerplate—just the meat and potatoes (the important parts) of your solution.

Note that, when posting an answer, your code and other content becomes licensed under [our standard CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). That basically means that anyone is free to use and remix your contributions, as long as they give you explicit credit for them (*i.e.*, attribution) and license the derivative work under a similar open license. If that's unacceptable to you, or you really want to share full programs, then you should do as Makoto suggested and simply provide a link in your profile, either to your personal homepage or a code-sharing site like GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab, etc.

Answer (score 3):

No, nothing like this exists.  The closest you can get is a link to your GitHub Gist in your profile.